# pass a string as argument in instance of a class, should have method that take string as an arg and perform according to instance.method

Tags: python

I want to create a instance of class **Token** that takes a string as an argument, this class should also have method **punc** that tokenize the string according to the method.instance. or raise an not implement error with a message. Problem is that I am new to OOP, class, attribute. I don't know how to pass the string as an argument and method will work on the string according to the string passed in class instance.

```
a = Token("a-z")
a.punc("Are you sure?")

output I am looking for "a-z" 
['Are','you','sure']

a = Token("c")
a.punc("Are you sure?")

output I am looking for "c"
['Are','you','sure?']
```

```
class Token:
    
    def __init__(self,string):
        self.az = "a-z"
        self.c = "c"
        self.string=string
       
        if "a-z" in string:
            string = string.split('?')
            
        if "c" in string:
            string = string.split()
          
        
    def punc (self,string):
        return self.string
```

output I get a-z which is not the right one. I know the coding is wrong, since I really not sure how to pass string as an argument. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Please clarify what you expect for each of your test cases, and why.  Your phrases fail to parse at critical places.  I'm guessing that you expect the `split` processing of `__init__` to somehow apply to the `string` passed into `punc`, even though you specifically return the original string you stored from `__init__`, and ignore the one you passed in.

Comment: It might help you if you use a common debugging technique: make sure that your functions have unique parameter names, so you *know* that they aren't the same variable.  For instance, change the header of `punc` to read `def punc(self, phrase)`.  Leave the creation function as as `__init__(self, string)`.  This will stop you from getting confused about your local variables.

Comment: @Prune yess, now I can understand where I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import re
class Token:
    
    def __init__(self, az):
        # we only initialize az in here 
        # which can hold only a-z or c
        self.az = az
        # string is empty
        self.string=''

    def punc(self, string):
        # now we check if the az was 'a-z' or 'c'
        if self.az=='a-z':
            # we then remove all non alpha numeric char
            # and split
            self.string = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', string).split()
            
        if self.az=='c':
            # or just split
            self.string = string.split()
        return self.string


a = Token("a-z")
print(a.punc("Are you sure?"))

b = Token("c")
print(b.punc("Are you sure?"))
```

result:

```
['Are', 'you', 'sure']
['Are', 'you', 'sure?']
```

Comment: Do not forget to mark the answer as the correct one if it helped :)

Comment: yess I upvoted, I wish I could mark everyone's answer as the correct one as all off the solution worked :)

Comment: oh, sorry i did not notice you already chosen a correct answer :)

Comment: your answer is chosen :)

Answer (score 1):

Look, `self.string` is a member of your class, and it has nothing with the parameter 'string' that you pass to the method `punc()`. To understand what it means, member of the class, try to print `a.string`. You'll get the value you pass during the object initialization, "a-z" for example.

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
class Token:
    
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string


    def punc (self, string):
        if "a-z" in self.string:
            return string.split()
            
        if c in self.stringstring::
            return string.split("?")
```

Here, I use `self.string` to keep your token value, and based on that value `punc()` will return the split string you passed.

Comment: yesss it worked. Thank you. Now I can see where I was doing silly mistake. This class thing seems confusing for me.

Comment: Yeah, at first it may seem a little difficult, but it's quite easy to understand if you keep learning.) and I should have mentioned that there are still some problems with the logic of the program, because I corrected only the OOP part. The rest is depended on your problem, so I didn't touch that

Answer (score 1):

I beleive the below should do the trick

```
class Token:

def __init__(self,rule):
    self.rule=rule
    self.text_Arr = []
      
    
def punc (self,text):
    print('I am looking for "' + self.rule + '"' )
    if "a-z" in self.rule:
        text = text.split("?")
        self.text_Arr = text[0].split(" ")
        return self.text_Arr
    elif "c" in self.rule:
        self.text_Arr = text.split(" ")
        return self.text_Arr
    else:
        print("Not implemented!")


a = Token("a-z")
print(a.punc("Are you sure?"))

b = Token("c")
print(a.punc("Are you sure?"))
```

Something to keep in mind is the Contructor usually used to initialise object.

Comment: Thank you. your solution worked. As a new to python, OOP seems confusing to me.

Comment: That's alright more than happy to help :)